# How to make certain JIRA issues only visible by a group of people?

Tags: jira, redmine, tracker

My company is trying JIRA and we were wondering if there is a way to make issues visible only by a certain group of people. For example if the issue was open in Germany it should only be visible by German users, if it was open in Japan only by Japanese users. The only exceptions are admin and devs that would be able to see globally.
In redmine this is fairly easy achieved with the sub-project feature, but how to do the same with JIRA?

PS: I would like it to be automatic and not based on a field the user has to chose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is not possible without a third-party plugin (or a custom plugin built for your JIRA).

JIRA has "issue security" concept that allows you to control who can see the issue. You can make an issue to be visible (by default) only to the Reporter and your staff. But you can't make it visible (automatically) to some group of users associated with the Reporter.

The shortest implementation path, from my point of view, would be to

1. Create a custom field of type "Group", call it "Visibility Group".
2. Create issue security scheme that by default would make the issue visible to your staff and to the members of the group selected in the "Visibility Group" field.
3. Create a custom plugin (or have an Atlassian Expert do that for you) that will set the default value of the Visibility Group field to some value based on the Reporter -- this can be added to the workflow as a post-function of the "Create" step.

There might be a plugin out there already for that, but quick search does not suggest anything.

Hope this helps!
Igor

Comment: Yeah it is the same conclusion I came to. Let see if someone else reply this...

Answer (score 2):

To restrict issue visibility in JIRA, you will have to define an **issue security schema** first. Atlassian offers a [**tutorial**](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Issue-level+Security) on that.

You will still have to assign your users to groups (more advisable) or roles first to be able to take advantage of the restrictions.

Comment: Still, the reporter or someone will have to assign a security level. It won't be automatic.

Comment: The issue reporter will have to be a memeber of a group, and the group membership, except for the "jira-users" group, is not atomatically assigned. So yes it won't be automatic, unfortunately, but it won't be the user/reporter who has to assign it.

Comment: The point, as I got it, is to assign different issue security levels based on what group the reporter belongs to (or maybe based on some other attribute of the user). Or to define a security level that would make an issue visible to the people who share the same group with the reporter. Neither of those are available so far.

Comment: @sereda - You are right, I'm afraid. Default JIRA configurability is not that flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we define the levels in the issue security scheme and then use something like the Script Runner plugin to create a post function that sets the issue security at creation.